# How to select penultimate (last but one) li element from the ul list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

and I need to addClass "extra" to the penultimate (e.g. if I have 5 li elements the extra class will be added to the 4th li element) from the ul list.

so the result in this case will be:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="extra">4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for teaching me a new word today, `penultimate`.

Comment: I'm going to +1 just for penultimate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("li:last").prev("li").addClass("class-to-add")
```

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: Thanks, it seems that only your version seems to work with my version of jQuery in Drupal.

Comment: @killingon: What version is that? Do `alert($.fn.jquery)` if you're not sure.

Comment: @killingon: I'd also be curious do know the jQuery version

Answer (score 8):

If there's only one list, just pass a negative index to the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
$("ul li").eq(-2).addClass("extra");
```

Sounds like you're using an older version of jQuery.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcVJq/) that shows it working in `jQuery 1.3.2`.

Comment: I thing this is the best answer. this offer a lot of possibilities .eq(-2) .eq(-n)

Answer (score 7):

```
$("ul li").last().prev().addClass("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all your `<li>` elements are siblings, and there's no other element between them, you can use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) followed by [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$("li").last().prev().addClass("extra");
```

Were there other elements in-between, you'd have to use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead:

```
$("li").last().prevAll("li").first().addClass("extra");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').eq($('li').length-2).addClass("extra")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = $("ul").children();
var penultimate = items.eq(items.length - 2);
penultimate.addClass("extra");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$('li').eq($('ul li').length - 2);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jMcH5/).

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).